# jQuery animate function possible syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

new to javascript/jquery.

Im getting the following error...

"Uncaught referenceError: $is not defined"

and it appears to be on the first line of the following script...

```
$('#button').toggle(
    function(){
        $('#menu-bar').animate({marginLeft: -200 }, 'slow', function(){
            $('#button').html('Close');
        });
    },
    function(){
        $('#menu-bar').animate({marginLeft: 200 }, 'slow', function(){
            $('#button').html('Menu');
        });
    }
);
```

css:

```
#button {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 100000;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#menu-bar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="menu-bar">
        <div id="button">Menu</div>
        <ul>
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: Have you added jQuery reference correctly ? you should cross check if it has loaded before you use $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to show code of how your importing jquery library. As i think what its saying is that '$' is not defined which suggested jquery hasn't loaded.

This shows how to initialise jquery [How should I initialize jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215904/how-should-i-initialize-jquery)